# Time column is not showing the time in the time_zone in which it is saved, in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone, strftime

i am having Time column in my table. and in`/config/application.rb` am having the following statement. `config.time_zone = 'Mumbai'`.

and iam saving the time in the database, with the following query

```
punch_rec.check_out = Time.now 
punch_rec.save
```

When i type the Time.now in the terminal it is showing the following time.

```
 2.2.2 :032 > Time.now
 => 2015-09-28 15:59:06 +0530
```

and when i retrieve the data from the database, then the time it is displaying in `UTC` time_zone. because of this in my view the time is displaying wrongly.

these are the steps iam executing.

```
2.2.2 :038 > p = PunchInOut.find_by_id("28")
  PunchInOut Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `punch_in_outs`.* FROM `punch_in_outs`  WHERE `punch_in_outs`.`id` = 28 LIMIT 1
 => #<PunchInOut id: 28, employee_id: 3, check_in: nil, check_out: nil, date: "2015-09-28", created_at: "2015-09-28 18:37:24", updated_at: "2015-09-28 10:25:22", shift_id: nil, shift_name: nil> 
2.2.2 :039 > p.check_in
 => nil 
2.2.2 :040 > Time.now
 => 2015-09-29 00:19:17 +0530 
2.2.2 :041 > p.check_in= Time.now
 => 2015-09-29 00:19:33 +0530 
2.2.2 :042 > p.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE `punch_in_outs` SET `check_in` = '2015-09-28 18:49:33', `updated_at` = '2015-09-28 18:49:38' WHERE `punch_in_outs`.`id` = 28
   (37.7ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
2.2.2 :043 > p = PunchInOut.find_by_id("28")
  PunchInOut Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `punch_in_outs`.* FROM `punch_in_outs`  WHERE `punch_in_outs`.`id` = 28 LIMIT 1
 => #<PunchInOut id: 28, employee_id: 3, check_in: "2000-01-01 18:49:33", check_out: nil, date: "2015-09-28", created_at: "2015-09-28 18:37:24", updated_at: "2015-09-28 18:49:38", shift_id: nil, shift_name: nil> 
2.2.2 :044 > p.check_in
 => 2000-01-01 18:49:33 UTC 
2.2.2 :045 >
```

how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Rails saves all times to the database in UTC by default, and then they are **displayed** in the appropriate timezone, being converted on the fly.  So, i'd expect the view to show the appropriately converted time.  Can you add the following info to your question: a)  what time LOCALLY do you think that `att.check_out` should be set to b) what is stored in the database, without converting it (look in your db terminal rather than using Rails) c) what is being displayed when you do `<%= att.check_out %>`

Comment: @MaxWilliams i updated my question.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, if rails saves every time in UTC time. then what is the use  ( `config.time_zone = 'Mumbai'`) of this statement? what it will do?

Comment: That is telling Rails which timezone to convert the UTC time to and from for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is set up to store time in UTC than that time will always be stored in UTC no matter what you do in your app. If you need to display that time to a user who is in some timezone different than UTC than you need to know what timezone he is in. If all your users are in a specific timezone than you can hard code that and display it in your app, for example something like this:

```
<%= p.check_in.in_time_zone('Mumbai').strftime("%H:%M") %>
```

If your users are in different timezones then you need to find that timezone first and then you need to display the time correctly. You can do that using some gems or with JavaScript which is the easiest solution. Check this [article](http://www.nikolatodorovic.com/nikolas-blog/rails-4-postgresql-timezone-best-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had a different timezone in your server. Try to store the value like this: `p.check_in = Time.zone.now`.

The main difference between `Time.now` and `Time.zone.now` is that the first one use server's timezone, and the second one use `application.rb`'s timezone.

Let me know if that works :)